# Second order difference equation in Python for Time Series

Tags: python, for-loop, equation

I want to simulate a second order difference equation from the book "Time Series Analysis" of James Hamilton.In page 13 there is an example :

Y[t] = 0.6*Y[t-1] + 0.2*Y[t-2] + w[t]

where w[t] is a random standard normal error.

My effort is in the code below.But I have two questions:

**1)** is that correct ?

**2)** how the range(n) changes ? For example 1:n or 2:n or (0,n-1) and (0,n-2) ?
I cannot understand completely how these ranges affect the for loop.

Any help?

```
import numpy as np
np.random.seed(123)
n = 1000
phi1 = 0.6
phi2 = 0.2
y = w = np.random.normal(size=n)
for t in range(n):
    y[t] = phi1* y[t-1] +phi2* y[t-2] + w[t]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At first glance, the for loop you have created starts from the first index, when you try to access t-2 when t = 0 the pointer moves to the second value from the end, which I don't think is what you intend to do, to fix this, try starting from 2.
as in ==> for t in range(2,n).
Furthermore, I did not quite understand your second question, but from what I understood your asking how the number T is incremented, which would be in the order {1,2,3,...,n}

Comment: Sorry for the inconvenience.Let's say I wanted only the y[t-1] the range would be (1,n) ?

Comment: yup, that is correct. Noted that the second parameter which is n, is never reached, so you should probably go range(1,n+1)

Comment: So back to my initial problem  nad according to your last comment the range must be (2,n+2) ?  I am more confused now

Comment: not quite, basically how range works is, lets say for the line (for t in range (n).  It changes t incrementally from the starting parameter, which would in our case be 0 and keeps incrementing t until it reaches n-1. But that is not what we want in our equation, we would like to start from the third element or index of 2(which are the same because most lists in programming start from 0, so you would count 0,1,2); because if we would start from 0, the term y[t-1] would be y[-1] which would take the element which is first from the end(this is a more advanced topic that has to do with pointers).

Comment: in our equation here, the correct line of code would be: (for t in range(2,n+1). Which would ensure that we start from the second index, and would also ensure that we include the last element, since range(n) does not reach the nth element(exclusive on the last element), in order to test this try to print t in range(10) like so ===> for t in range(10): print t // and then you can conclude that the 10th element is not reached because 10 is not printed